# Change color of 3D object in Android

Tags: android, colors, arcore

I have loaded a 3D object using Sceneform in Android app. I enabled AR core and used fragment as [Google Developers ARCore example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sceneform-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018#0)

Now I need to change that loaded object color at runtime when a button is clicked.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Today, we can only access the material quality of the object.

But you can have the same Object in different colours and when hit the button you change the object using the same anchor

Comment: can't we even change color of a 3D object which is loaded on a `ModelSurfaceView` in open gl?  The object build by using `Object3DBuilder.loadV6AsyncParallel()` method.